# Access from Azure CDN to ip-restricted Azure Web App - Which IP ranges should be whitelisted?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cdn

We have a staging environment (Azure Web App) to which the access is restricted via Azure's IP Restriction feature. Currently we are in the process of adding an Azure CDN to serve static content, but we are having problems with the connection between the CDN and our IP restricted site.

This is of course due to the fact that the CDN connects from a number of different non-whitelisted IP's, but I am having troubles figuring out which IP ranges I should whitelist. Any ideas?

Our Azure elements are hosted in the "West Europe" location. Our Azure CDN uses the standard Microsoft pricing tier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the Azure Data Center IP Ranges over here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653

They're grouped by region, so you should be able to get the specific IP ranges for West Europe pretty easily.

Comment: And there is no way to narrow it down? There are close to 100 ip-adresses/ranges for west Europe.

Comment: I'd have thought you'd need to whitelist all CDN ip's as any could be hitting your origin. Not just those from West Europe.